# How does my program get notified of system's standby/hibernate mode and restart?

Tags: java, sleep, power-management, standby, acpi

Is there a platform independent possibility for Java programs to receive APM or ACPI events when the system goes into standby mode or hibernation - and again when it returns from these modes?

(So that one has the possibility to e.g. delete a half written file on a network drive, before the system goes down?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like it requires direct interaction with the operating system. Unless this capability is added to the java api, you can't do it in a platform-independent way. You could write native methods for this purpose, but you must rewrite them for different platforms.